# What is the difference between arrayListOf and mutableListOf , which one is better?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to use collections in Kotlin and got confused between arrayListOf and mutableListOf, which one should we use and why?

Answer (score 6):

Either is fine, the only difference between calling the two is expressing your intent.

`ArrayList` is a concrete implementation of `MutableList`, and `mutableListOf`, as of Kotlin 1.1, also returns an `ArrayList`.

Do you know you specifically want an ArrayList because you have made the conscious decision that this is the right choice for your application? You probably want `arrayListOf` (or a direct call to the `ArrayList` constructor, if that interface works better for you).

Do you just want a MutableList of some sort, and are fine with getting whatever the implementation defines as the right choice? Just use `mutableListOf` instead.