# Is there any reference for Kotlin standard Collection library time complexity?

Tags: collections, time-complexity, kotlin

For example, Scala has the official [Collections Performance Characteristics](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) page that shows the time complexity of methods like `apply()`(get in Java), `insert()`, and `append()` in collections like `List`, `Array`, and `ArrayBuffer`.

However, I cannot find such kind of information in Kotlin.

The Kotlin stdlib API page also does not have such information. Even worse, I don't get the information about the underlying implementation of [List](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) (created by [listOf()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) or so), for example unless I dig into the source code.

So does `List` in Kotlin take O(n) time accessing an element, and take O(1) time appending an element?

Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kotlin stdlib does not contain its own collections, on JVM `listOf` is just a binding to Java's `Collections.emptyList()`, `Collections.singletonList()`, and `ArrayList`. ArrayList has O(1) positional access complexity.

Comment: If `listOf()` corresponds to `ArrayList` in JVM, then what is the purpose of `arrayListOf()` in Kotlin?

Comment: OK maybe this is that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182333/what-is-the-difference-between-arraylistof-and-mutablelistof-which-one-is-bett

Comment: `listOf()` is a `List`, `mutableListOf()` is a `MutableList`, `arrayListOf()` is an `ArrayList()`. So, List is for reading purposes, MutableList can be changed, and ArrayList is a concrete MutableList implementation.